# Find a pending lock or transaction in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, locking

I have a piece of PHP code which can't execute queries anymore because of a pending lock or already open transaction on the MySql DB which i still haven't found.
The script is launched by cron every hour. The offending code is this

```
    CommandHelper::log("Calling beginTransaction for item $item->id");
    $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    CommandHelper::log("Trying to get update lock for item $item->id");
    try {
       // this line will lock a single row
        $item = Item::model()->findBySql("SELECT * FROM " . $item::model()->getTableSchema()->name . " WHERE id=$item->id FOR UPDATE");
        if(!$item)
            throw new Exception("Item $item->id not found in processItem");
        CommandHelper::log("Obtained update lock for item $item->id");


    $now = DateTimeHelper::getInstance()->getStringNow();
    // the following call executes a few queries and causes an exception
    $this->processExpiredDeferredPayments($item,$now);
    // we won't get here
    CommandHelper::log("Item $item->id query confirmed units");
   ....
   ....

        $transaction->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollBack();            
        CommandHelper::log("Transaction error:" . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

The log prints these lines every hour:

```
...
...
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Item 164 start processing
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Calling beginTransaction for item 164
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Trying to get update lock for item 164
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Obtained update lock for item 164
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Transaction error:There is already an active transaction
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Item 164 end processing
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Item 160 start processing
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Calling beginTransaction for item 160
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Trying to get update lock for item 160
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Obtained update lock for item 160
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Transaction error:There is already an active transaction
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Item 160 end processing
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Item 182 start processing
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Calling beginTransaction for item 182
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Trying to get update lock for item 182
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Obtained update lock for item 182
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Transaction error:There is already an active transaction
2017-06-03 14:46:04 Item 182 end processing
...
...
```

This is the output of `show engine innodb status`

```
=====================================
2017-06-03 15:00:16 2af55a655700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 10 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 139314 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 2478167 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 2617481
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 139170
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 139073
Mutex spin waits 15233, rounds 456961, OS waits 14580
RW-shared spins 123701, rounds 3711390, OS waits 123173
RW-excl spins 89, rounds 42528, OS waits 1410
Spin rounds per wait: 30.00 mutex, 30.00 RW-shared, 477.84 RW-excl
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 233590159
Purge done for trx's n:o < 233589999 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 2636
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 225441219, not started
MySQL thread id 271018, OS thread handle 0x2af55a655700, query id 28702104 172.31.10.242 ebroot init
show engine innodb status
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 271017, OS thread handle 0x2af55bfa6700, query id 28698794 172.31.10.242 ebroot cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 233590158, not started
MySQL thread id 1, OS thread handle 0x2af55a550700, query id 28702102 localhost 127.0.0.1 rdsadmin cleaning up
   --------
   FILE I/O
   --------
   ...
   ...
```

And this is the output of `show full processlist`:

[image]

Which is the pending transaction or lock here and how to kill it?

And why it did not get automatically closed when the PHP script ends?
I thought that even though a PHP thread has a Mysql connection, when the thread  exits the MySQL connection is automatically closed and the transactions/locks started by it should be automatically committed or rolled back, no ?
Thanks

Comment: I notice some transactions in the innodb status show they are stuck "cleaning up." This sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44289981/20860 so take a look at my answer there. It might help to upgrade MySQL if the same bug is affecting you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the issue.

Inside the processExpiredDeferredPayments method i forgot that i was opening another transaction there, and since a transaction was already opened , Mysql raised an exception.

Now it works, both with Mysql 5.16 and 5.35. No need to upgrade for now

Thanks everybody